# How to properly merge several API calls that return observables into a single interface array?

Tags: arrays, angular, api, observable, ngrx

Back-End holds several databases to whom I need to make API calls on to gather a dataset that I require to display the information.
Im using **angular 12** and **NGRX** for state management.

API Requests are cast on to observables.

I'm trying to combine several observable arrays into a single observable array since I don't have an idea of how to pass in multiple objects to a selector and a reducer

So far I'm able to get the data and combine it but the output of **getUtilities()** instead of an observable array that I could pass to a selector I get several objects that the selctor does not how to deal with.

Redux shows that the action of successfull retreiving the data is executed 4 times. [image: Redux showing that successful load action is triggered 4 times]

My question is - How do I merge the API data into a single utiltiesList array without the need to call the backend several hundred times.

**data.service.ts** file contains all the API call functions

```
  getActiveProperties(): Observable<Property[]> {
    return this.http.get<Property[]>(this.getPropertiesUrl).pipe(
      mergeMap((data) => {
        return of(data);
      })
    );
  }

  getCurrentUtilities(
    currentMonth: string,
    currentYear: string
  ): Observable<utilities[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<utilities[]>(
        `${this.getUtiltiesUrl}?month=${currentMonth}&year=${currentYear}`
      )
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((data) => {
          return of(data);
        })
      );
  }

getPreviousUtilities(
    previousMonth: string,
    previousYear: string
  ): Observable<utilitiesPrevious[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<utilities[]>(
        `${this.getUtiltiesUrl}?month=${previousMonth}&year=${previousYear}`
      )
      .pipe(
        map((response) =>
          response.map(
            (sp): utilitiesPrevious => ({
              propertyID: sp.propertyID,
              cold1Prev: sp.cold1,
              cold2Prev: sp.cold2,
              hot1Prev: sp.hot1,
              hot2Prev: sp.hot2,
              gasPrev: sp.gas,
              electricityPrev: sp.electricity,
            })
          )
        )
      );

  getUtilityComments(): Observable<utilitiesComments[]> {
    return this.http.get<utilitiesComments[]>(`${this.getCommentsUrl}`).pipe(
      mergeMap((data) => {
        return of(data);
      })
    );
  }
```

To combine the data I've created this "beautiful" piece of code:

```
getUtilities(
    currentMonth: string,
    currentYear: string,
    previousMonth: string,
    previousYear: string
  ): Observable<utilitiesList[]> {
    const properties = this.getActiveProperties();
    const currentUtilities = this.getCurrentUtilities(
      currentMonth,
      currentYear
    );
    const previousUtilities = this.getPreviousUtilities(
      previousMonth,
      previousYear
    );
     const comments = this.getUtilityComments();

    return forkJoin([properties, currentUtilities, previousUtilities, comments])
      .pipe(
        switchMap((response) => [
          ...response[0]
            .map((item1) => ({
              ...response[1].find(
                (item2) => item2.propertyID === item1.propertyID && item2
              ),
              ...item1,
            }))
            .map((item1) => ({
              ...response[2].find(
                (item2) => item2.propertyID === item1.propertyID && item2
              ),
              ...item1,
            }))
            .map((item1) => ({
              ...response[3].find(
                (item2) => item2.propertyID === item1.propertyID && item2
              ),
              ...item1,
            })),
        ])
      )
      .pipe(map((data: unknown) => <utilitiesList[]>data));
  }
```

Here is a sample set of what the API Calls are returning:
**getActiveProperties()**

```
[
  {
    "propertyID": 1,
    "AddressL1": "add1",
    "AddressL2": "cityA",
    "zip": "XXYYYY"
  },
  {
    "propertyID": 2,
    "AddressL1": "add2",
    "AddressL2": "cityB",
    "zip": "XXYYYY"
  },
  {
    "propertyID": 3,
    "AddressL1": "add3",
    "AddressL2": "cityC",
    "zip": "XXYYYY"
  },
  {
    "propertyID": 4,
    "AddressL1": "add4",
    "AddressL2": "cityD",
    "zip": "XXYYYY"
  }
]
```

**getCurrentUtilities()**

```
[
  {
    "utilityID": 77,
    "cold1": 169,
    "cold2": 145,
    "hot1": 153,
    "hot2": 153,
    "gas": 143,
    "electricity": 994,
    "month": 8,
    "year": 2021,
    "propertyID": 4,
    "commentID": 4
  }
]
```

**getPreviousUtilities()**

```
  {
    "utilityID": 19,
    "cold1": 165,
    "cold2": 167,
    "hot1": 158,
    "hot2": 158,
    "gas": 187,
    "electricity": 1015,
    "month": 7,
    "year": 2021,
    "propertyID": 1,
    "commentID": 1
  },
  {
    "utilityID": 38,
    "cold1": 170,
    "cold2": 162,
    "hot1": 154,
    "hot2": 155,
    "gas": 119,
    "electricity": 1082,
    "month": 7,
    "year": 2021,
    "propertyID": 2,
    "commentID": 2
  },
  {
    "utilityID": 57,
    "cold1": 148,
    "cold2": 176,
    "hot1": 175,
    "hot2": 139,
    "gas": 166,
    "electricity": 1065,
    "month": 7,
    "year": 2021,
    "propertyID": 3,
    "commentID": 3
  },
  {
    "utilityID": 76,
    "cold1": 165,
    "cold2": 142,
    "hot1": 149,
    "hot2": 149,
    "gas": 135,
    "electricity": 969,
    "month": 7,
    "year": 2021,
    "propertyID": 4,
    "commentID": 4
  }
]
```

**getUtilityComments**

```
[
  {
    "propertyID": 1,
    "Cold1Com": "Nr.6918",
    "Cold2Com": "Nr.5773",
    "Hot1Com": "Nr.7719",
    "Hot2Com": "Nr.5880",
    "GasCom": "Nr.2427",
    "ElectCom": "Nr.2744",
    "Comment": "Comm1"
  },
  {
    "propertyID": 2,
    "Cold1Com": "Nr.8573",
    "Cold2Com": "Nr.9652",
    "Hot1Com": "Nr.1279",
    "Hot2Com": "Nr.3600",
    "GasCom": "Nr.1730",
    "ElectCom": "Nr.1865",
    "Comment": "Comm2"
  },
  {
    "propertyID": 3,
    "Cold1Com": "Nr.6214",
    "Cold2Com": "Nr.9956",
    "Hot1Com": "Nr.8015",
    "Hot2Com": "Nr.8445",
    "GasCom": "Nr.4348",
    "ElectCom": "Nr.4714",
    "Comment": "Comm3"
  },
  {
    "propertyID": 4,
    "Cold1Com": "Nr.5625",
    "Cold2Com": "Nr.7039",
    "Hot1Com": "Nr.6681",
    "Hot2Com": "Nr.8978",
    "GasCom": "Nr.7224",
    "ElectCom": "Nr.6826",
    "Comment": "Comm4"
  }
]
```

All of the API requests have a common field - **propertyID** which is a number.
Here's the list of interfaces for the respective objects:

```
export interface utilities {
  utilityID: number;
  propertyID: number;
  cold1: number | null;
  cold2: number | null;
  hot1: number | null;
  hot2: number | null;
  gas: number | null;
  electricity: number | null;

}

export interface utilitiesPrevious {

  cold1Prev: number | null;
  cold2Prev: number | null;
  hot1Prev: number | null;
  hot2Prev: number | null;
  gasPrev: number | null;
  electricityPrev: number | null;
  propertyID: number;
}

export interface utilitiesComments {
  propertyID: number;
  Cold1Com: string | null;
  Cold2Com: string | null;
  Hot1Com: string | null;
  Hot2Com: string | null;
  GasCom: string | null;
  ElectCom: string | null;
  Comment: string | null;
}

export interface utilitiesList {
  utilityID: number;
  propertyID: number;

  cold1: number | null;
  cold2: number | null;
  hot1: number | null;
  hot2: number | null;
  gas: number | null;
  electricity: number | null;

  cold1Prev: number | null;
  cold2Prev: number | null;
  hot1Prev: number | null;
  hot2Prev: number | null;
  gasPrev: number | null;
  electricityPrev: number | null;

  Cold1Com: string | null;
  Cold2Com: string | null;
  Hot1Com: string | null;
  Hot2Com: string | null;
  GasCom: string | null;
  ElectCom: string | null;
  Comment: string | null;

  AddressL1: string | null;
  AddressL2: string | null;
  zip: string | null;
  Tennant_ID: number | null;
  Lease_ID: number | null;
  Previous_Leases: number | null;
  Sold: number | null;
  Date_Sold: Date | null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `map` operator should be used instead of `switchMap` within the `getUtilities` method.

`switchMap` operator maps to an observable, not to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the operator from *switchMap* to *map* did the trick, thank you so much!

This is the function that returns the desired output:

```
 getUtilities(
    currentMonth: string,
    currentYear: string,
    previousMonth: string,
    previousYear: string
  ): Observable<utilitiesList[]> {
    const properties = this.getActiveProperties();
    const currentUtilities = this.getCurrentUtilities(
      currentMonth,
      currentYear
    );
    const previousUtilities = this.getPreviousUtilities(
      previousMonth,
      previousYear
    );
    const comments = this.getUtilityComments();

    return forkJoin([properties, currentUtilities, previousUtilities, comments])
      .pipe(
        map((response) => [
          ...response[0]
            .map((item1) => ({
              ...response[1].find(
                (item2) => item2.propertyID === item1.propertyID && item2
              ),
              ...item1,
            }))
            .map((item1) => ({
              ...response[2].find(
                (item2) => item2.propertyID === item1.propertyID && item2
              ),
              ...item1,
            }))
            .map((item1) => ({
              ...response[3].find(
                (item2) => item2.propertyID === item1.propertyID && item2
              ),
              ...item1,
            })),
        ])
      )
      .pipe(map((data: unknown) => <utilitiesList[]>data));
  }
```